# readCharArray() Method is not working

Tags: java

I have a problem with a method which i want to use to read a complete line of characters.

First of all i'm using the following package for my method:

```
package chararray;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Console
{
 private static Scanner sc;  
 private Console()
 {  

 }   

 public static char[] readCharArray() 
  throws NoSuchElementException, IllegalStateException
 {
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = sc.nextLine();
    return text.toCharArray();
 }   

}
```

And that's the main code where i include the package. My compiler (BlueJ) is telling me: "incompatible types - found char[] but expected char". But normally my method should work for char[]? Any suggestions what i'm doing wrong here?

```
import chararray.Console;

public class kundenverwaltung
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int nk;

        System.out.print("Wie viele Kunden möchten Sie erfassen?: ");
        nk = Console.readInt();

        char [][] kundenregister;
        kundenregister = new char [nk][4];

        for (int i = 0; i < nk; ++i)

        {
            System.out.print("Kundennummer: ");
            kundenregister [i][0] = Console.readCharArray();

            System.out.print("Name des Kunden: ");
            kundenregister [i][1] = Console.readCharArray();

            System.out.print("Vorname des Kunden: ");
            kundenregister [i][2] = Console.readCharArray();

            System.out.print("Adresse des Kunden: ");
            kundenregister [i][3]  = Console.readCharArray();

        }      

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
kundenregister[i][0] = Console.readCharArray();
```

The expression `kundenregister[i][0]` refers to a `char` variable - not a char array.

It's not clear what you're trying to do - and in particular why you need the values as char arrays rather than as strings - but this would make it work:

```
char[][][] kundenregister = new char[nk][4][];
```

Having a 3-dimensional array is almost *always* a mistake. I would *strongly* suggest that you refactor the code to:

- Use strings instead of `char` arrays
- Encapsulate the 4 values into a type with properties for the number, name, first name and address
- Create a `List<Customer>` or whatever... perhaps using `ArrayList<T>` as the implementation. Then you don't even need to know the number of customers beforehand... the user could just hit return (or whatever) to indicate that they'd finished.

Comment: And @Ordo: Even if you use Strings, you can still use methods like `substring()` and `charAt` to access individual characters or regions of the string.

Comment: Yes after seeing that this is I guess reading the name, address, etc of a person from the command line, making a class and using Strings is absolutely critical here.  Don't work with char arrays here, period.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `kundenregister` is declared as an array of arrays of chars.  That means that for each x and y, `kundenregister[x][y]` is a *single char* (the yth character of the xth array of characters).  Yet you are trying to assign it an entire array of characters.

I'm not sure what your goal is here so I can't suggest an easy fix.  You either want to assign the result to some index of `kundenregister` or declare `kundenregister` as a 3-dimensional array.

Comment: Oh, i understand. So i must declare "kundenregister" as an 3-dimensional array.

Comment: @Ordo: maybe.  That would solve your compilation problems, but since it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish or what your code is supposed to do, I couldn't say whether it's appropriate or not.

Comment: I want to store for each "customer" a set of data  e.g. customer number, customer name and so on. My suggestions was to make a two dimensional array kundenregister [i] [j] and store for each customer [i] a set of data in the second dimension [0,1,2..j]. But since the data, which i want to store, has more than one character it seems as if i must use a third dimension to store it. Is there another "smarter" possiblity?

Comment: @Ordo: yes, see Jon Skeet's answer.  You should not be dealing in characters at all, and you should use a class to hold those fields instead of using an array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here so I can't offer a full solution, but the immediate problem causing the error is in your `kundenverwaltung` class, in the for loop.

You're trying to assign Console.readCharArray() to `kundenregister[i][0]`, which is where the type mismatch occurs since Console.readCharArray() returns a `char[]`, and `kundenregister[i][0]` is of type `char`.

To help you understand this: `kundenregister` is essentially a 2d grid, where each slot is a single char. `kundenregister[i][0]` refers to one of those slots, so when you write `kundenregister[i][2] = x`, `x` has to be a char otherwise it won't work.